# internal compiler error: in decode_addr_const, at varasm.c:2632

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, embedded-linux, u-boot

When I compile a project using cross compiler,I come across the following error:

```
internal compiler error: in decode_addr_const, at varasm.c:2632
```

Where can I find the varasm.c file?I searched the project directory and cross compiler directory,but I didn't find it.
Thanks for helpping,Light

Answer (score -4):

The compiler maker has that file, and probably won't give it to you.
But as it seems to be an error in the compiler, you can either contact them / file a bug report, or try to avoid the error by changing your code a bit (which is a guessing game, as you don't know how you made it run into the error). Or use another compiler, if there are choices.

Comment: I ran a simple Google search, and was able to figure out the compiler in about 30 seconds. No big deal.